# Asp.net C# Custom SQL in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I need to show every record which equals the var modid and the current session's userid.

In .cs code this would be:

```
SELECT Mod_Naam 
FROM Model 
WHERE Mod_ID = " + modid + " 
AND User_ID = '" + Session["status"].ToString() + "'
```

How can I import this query in a dropdownlist?

I may also need to use this on a gridview.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this query in a dropdownlist" ? Do you mean the `modid` variable is returned in the `IndexChanged` event of your dropdownlist? or do the results of that query need to be shown in a dropdownlist. Please clarify

Comment: Is you intention to filter the results in a grid where one of the parameters is the selection of the dropdown? Or do you want to set the items of the dropdown to the result of that query?  Either way if you want to include the SQL directly in your web app without a business or datalayer you should be able to do this with a combination of SqlDataSources.  You can also set a dropdown to provide the parameter for the grid's datasource

Comment: It's the querry I would like to use for selecting the items I wanna show in my dropdownlist (got nothing to do with the IndexChanged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from a DB via the `DataTable` and then bind that `DataTable` to the dropdownlist as follows:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
    { 
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Mod_Naam FROM Model WHERE Mod_ID = " + modid + " AND User_ID = '" + Session["status"].ToString() + "' "";
       //cmd.Parameters.Add(param);// You add parameter


        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) 
        { 
            da.Fill(dt); 
        }
```

Take a look here, on how to get Data in DataTable [Retrieve a DataTable using a SQL Statement](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/07/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-sql-statement.aspx)

```
DropDownList1.DataSourceID = dt;
DropDownList1.DataTextField= "Mod_Naam";
DropDownList1.DataValueField= "Mod_Naam";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Also please use query parameters in stead of concatenating the variables in your query. Always better to prevent than to cure :-)

Comment: I have commented that code and wrote comment, he have to modified that query a bit.

Comment: Oh yes, I saw that. I didn't mean it towards you, @Muhammad. you did great by adding that in comment :-)